# How do I median-center my data?

Tags: matlab, median

I have a 1x600 vector that I have log2 transformed and now I wish to median center. Does anyone know the code for this in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract the median value from the data value. Here is an example if you want to perform median centering on the log transformed data.

```
medianValue = median(logData);
medianCtrData = logData-medianValue;
```

Comment: In case you need to center the raw data, revert the log-transformation with 2^logData, then apply the code of kl3755, and apply the log2 again.

Comment: log is a monotonic transformation for positive reals, so the identity of the median won't change as @tashuhka mentioned.